# GeoTools getFeature request 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: java, geotools

I am having trouble while trying to make a `getFeature` request to a WFS server. I can make `getCapabilities` and `describeFeatureType` request.

```
 String getCapabilities = "http://cbsservis.tkgm.gov.tr/tkgm.ows/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=Getcapabilities";
    Map<String, String> connectionParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:USERNAME", "cbsdemouser");
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:PASSWORD", "lp+12345");
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL",
            getCapabilities);
    try {
        DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);
        String typeNames[] = null;
        typeNames = data.getTypeNames();
        String typeName = typeNames[0];
        SimpleFeatureType schema = data.getSchema(typeName);
        System.out.println("Schema Attributes:"
                + schema.getAttributeCount());

        SimpleFeatureSource source = data.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        System.out.println("Metadata Bounds:" + source.getBounds());

        FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(GeoTools
                .getDefaultHints());

        DefaultQuery query = new DefaultQuery(typeName, Filter.INCLUDE);
        query.setMaxFeatures(2);

        SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures(query);

        String fid = null;

        Iterator<SimpleFeature> iterator = (Iterator<SimpleFeature>) features
                .features();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature feature = (SimpleFeature) iterator.next();
            fid = feature.getID();
            System.out.println(fid);
        }
```

But when I tried to make a `getFeature` request, I got this errors:

```
WARNING: Unexpected response "401 Unauthorized" while downloading http://cbsservis.tkgm.gov.tr/tkgm.ows/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=TKGM%3Aadalar
Eyl 08, 2015 10:23:45 AM org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.NonStrictWFSStrategy createFeatureReaderGET
WARNING: java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Failed to resolve 
Eyl 08, 2015 10:23:45 AM org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.NonStrictWFSStrategy createFeatureReaderPOST
WARNING: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
```

Comment: which WFS plugin are you using classic or NG?

Comment: i am using classic WFS plugin